# Update div using Ajax by clicking on marker in Google Maps

Tags: ajax, google-maps, html, markers

I'm try to update a div using Ajax on a webpage when you clicked on a Google maps marker. I'm experimenting with some code, but it doesn't want to work. The code is below; basically, when you click on one of the three test markers, you should get the contents of simple files (1.html, 2.html, 3.html) saying "You clicked on 1", "You clicked on 2" etc. displayed in the "showdata" div.

The simple test code is below. I've commented out the troublesome code; The one labelled *1 doesn't seem to work; after putting the first marker on the map, it doesn't bother with the other two. Even with the bulk of the infoCallback(name) function commented out, as below, it produces nothing, whereas it should really return without doing anything at all (?)

I've done some research on this matter but the solutions involve updating a marker's infoWindow itself using Ajax, and not a div on the main webpage itself.

As I said, the code is just a prototype, proof of concept so its a bit messy ;)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.map-content h3 { margin: 0; padding: 5px 0 0 0; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">  </script>
<script>
// Set the Map variable
var map;
function initialize() { 
var myOptions = {
zoom: 2,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
panControl: true,
zoomControl: true,
scaleControl: true
};


var alldata = [ ["1", "50.8925", "-1.398611"],["2", "50.897222", "-1.396667"],["3", "50.896944", "-1.394167"]
];  

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
// Set the center of the map
map.setZoom(16);
var pos = new google.maps.LatLng("50.895", "-1.397");
map.setCenter(pos);

setMarkers(map, alldata);
}

function setMarkers(map, alldata) 
{   
    for (var i in alldata) 
    {   
        var name = alldata[i][0];
            var lat = alldata[i][1];
            var lng = alldata[i][2];

        var latlngset;
            latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latlngset});

//google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', infoCallback(name)); //*1
// commented out because it doesn't work
         }

}

// Initializes the Google Map
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


infoCallback(name) 
{  

// goes in div showdata

/*
var response;

var sendurl = name + ".html";

var xmlhttp;
var generated_html="";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}
else
{

xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{

if(xmlhttp.readyState==2)
{

document.getElementById('showdata').innerHTML='<center>Please wait...processing...<p><img src="green_rot.gif"></center>';
}

if(xmlhttp.readyState==3)
{

document.getElementById('showdata').innerHTML='<center>Please wait...processing...<p><img src="green_rot.gif"></center>';
}

if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById('showdata').innerHTML = response;
}

} // end of anonymous function above

xmlhttp.open("GET",sendurl,true);
xmlhttp.send();
*/

} // end of function

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 1100px;"></div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="showdata"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bit of a scope problem there among other things.

First thing you should put function in front of infocallback (but i guess that is just a copy paste error)

second

```
//google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', infoCallback(name)); //*1
```

if you call infoCallback(name) like that it will be executed right away so it should be

```
//google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', infoCallback); //*1
```

But of course you cannot give your name like that and infoCallBack would only get a mouseevent

So to solve that its best to put a closer there that calls infoCallback and gives the name.
However the problem would then be that you will always give the last name you set. To solve this add a new function setMarker that is called each loop of your setMarkers.

See the code below that shows the changes and a truncated version of infoCallBack (i just uses that to test)

```
     function setMarkers(map, alldata) {
        for (var i in alldata) {
            var name = alldata[i][0];
            var lat = alldata[i][1];
            var lng = alldata[i][2];

            var latlngset;
            latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            setMarker(map, latlngset, name);
        }
    }

    function setMarker(map, latlngset, name)
    {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: latlngset});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infoCallback(name);
        });
    }

    function infoCallback(name) {
        console.debug(name);
    }
```

As the code is a prototype i am sure you can adapt this to your needs